# ¿Como puedo obtener la ubicacion de un componente en relacion a la pantalla?

Tags: java, java-swing

Quiero obtener la ubicacion de un componente en relación a la pantalla, pero al usar el método `getLocation()`, obtengo la ubicación del componente en relación a el otro componente donde se encuentra ubicado el mismo.

Comment: ya intentaste mediante `getLocationOnScreen()`?

Comment: Hola, si, no sabia de la existencia de ese método, gracias.

Comment: avisanos si te sirve o no para poderte dar una respuesta

Comment: sisi me ha servido, perdona no me he expresado bien en el comentario anterior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yaque mencionas un componente, asumiremos que te refieres a una subclase de `Component`

como lo menciona en [su documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen()) esta clase tiene un método llamado `getLocationOnScreen()` te permitirá obtener las coordenadas en base al espacio de coordenadas de la pantalla.

Esto se refiere que la esquina superior izquierda de la pantalla tendrá la posición `0,0` y a partir de allí se irá incrementando.